# TableLayoutPane missing in Visual Studio 17

Tags: visual-studio

Ive been using TableLayoutPane in Visual Studio 2015 to create form designs and recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017. But the TableLayoutPane has been missing in the newer version!! What is the solution here?

[image]

Comment: Try searching on Internet first, you will find it on many websites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem myself guys. What I did is :

1. Right click on container(or any other) tab inside the Toolbox an click on "Choose items..."
2. Then a dialogue pops up and under .NET components search for TableLayoutPane and check it to make it visible in Toolbox

Comment: I did and no TableLayoutPanel nor Timer controls shown.

Comment: i could see only common controls; did a reset and everything turned to normal... why has vs to be so weird sometimes